# Variables called through function return zero

Tags: excel, vba

I used "step into" to see that VBA gets the correct answer.

When I call the variable into another sub, it returns zero.

```vb
Sub ComboBox5_Change()
    
    Call htot
    Dim h As Double
    
    TextBox4.Value = h

End Sub

Sub htot()

    Call daltutil
    Call cobr
    Dim h As Long
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
            
    h = (d + c + 0.5)
    
End Sub

Sub daltutil()

    Call Contengaste
    Call lengaste
    
    Dim d As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim l As Long
        
    d = (2.5 - (0.1 * n)) * l
    
End Sub

Sub cobr()

    Dim c As Long
    
    If ComboBox5.Text = "Classe I" Then
        c = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox5.Text = "Classe II" Then
        c = 2.5
    ElseIf ComboBox5.Text = "Classe III" Then
        c = 3.5
    ElseIf ComboBox5.Text = "Classe IV" Then
        c = 4.5
    End If

End Sub

Sub lengaste()

    Dim l As Long
    
    lx = TextBox2.Value
    lypond = (TextBox1.Value * 0.7)
    
    If lx > lypond Then
        l = lypond
    Else: l = lx
    
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub Contengaste()

    Dim n As Long
        
    If ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 4
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 3
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 3
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 3
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 3
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 1
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 1
    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 1
    ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 1
        
    End If
           
End Sub
```

After making the changes suggested, it looks like this:

```
Sub ComboBox5_Change()
    
    Dim h As Long
    h = htot
    TextBox4.Value = h

End Sub

Function htot() As Double

    Dim h As Double
    Dim d As Double
    Dim c As Double
    
    d = daltutil
    c = cobr
            
    h = (d + c + 0.5)
    
    htot = h
    
End Function

Function daltutil() As Double
   
    Dim d As Double
    Dim n As Double
    Dim l As Double
    
    n = Contengaste
    l = lengaste
        
    d = (2.5 - (0.1 * n)) * l
    
End Function

Function cobr() As Double

    Dim c As Double
    
    If ComboBox5.Text = "Classe I" Then
        c = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox5.Text = "Classe II" Then
        c = 2.5
    ElseIf ComboBox5.Text = "Classe III" Then
        c = 3.5
    ElseIf ComboBox5.Text = "Classe IV" Then
        c = 4.5
    End If

End Function

Function lengaste() As Double

    Dim l As Double
    
    lx = TextBox2.Value
    lypond = (TextBox1.Value * 0.7)
    
    If lx > lypond Then
        l = lypond
    Else: l = lx
    
    End If
    
End Function

Function Contengaste() 

    Dim n As Double
        
    If ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 4
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 3
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 3
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 3
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 3
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" And ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 2
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 1
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 1
    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 1
    ElseIf ComboBox4.Text = "Engaste" Then
        n = 1
        
    End If
           
End Function
```

I still get zeros from every function. I tried changing the contengaste back from function to sub to see if there would be a change, but it returns zero into other function.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things, you have decimals so you want a `double` not a `long`.

Subs don't return values so make anything with a return a function.

Assign your variables to the return of the functions.

```
Sub ComboBox5_Change()
    Dim h As Double 'Double here or you will get an integer not a decimal
    h = htot 'Assign the value

    TextBox4.Value = h

End Sub

Function htot() As Double 'Note the Function not Sub
    
    Dim h As Double 'Double here or you will get an integer not a decimal
    Dim d As Double
    Dim c As Double
    d = daltutil
    c = cobr

            
    h = (d + c + 0.5)
    
    htot = h 'Return the value
End Function
```

You can also pass something `ByRef` though it doesn't make a lot of sense to do so in your current code. It would look something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim h As Double
    h = 5
    Debug.Print h
    doublevalue h
    Debug.Print h
End Sub

Sub doublevalue(ByRef val As Double)
    val = val * 2
End Sub
```

Comment: So:
1) I changed the Long's to Double's, and also added it to the Function's declaration;
2) I deleted the "Call" procedures, and instead used the variable system (i.e. n = contengaste)
I think, overall, it was the main points you pointed on the code above. But still, zeros.

Comment: Did you add returns to the functions and change any sub that has a return to a function?

Comment: The functions are looking like this now:

Function htot() As Double

    Dim h As Double
    Dim d As Double
    Dim c As Double
    
    d = daltutil
    c = cobr
            
    h = (d + c + 0.5)
    
    htot = h

Comment: That should do it, it works for me. If you step through what is the value of ```h``` after ```h = htot```. Do you have a change event on that text box that is setting it back to zero or something?

Comment: It is returning 0.5. I edited the code in the question, to show what looks like now

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but Subs can call functions, but functions can't call functions. Is it right?

Comment: No a function can call a function. If it is returning .5 then the other values are 0. You need to update every sub that is returning something to be a function and add in its return I only did the first one in my example but it is the same idea for them all.

Comment: It worked, the problem was the return to the same function at the end of each one. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a concept in programming that you need to understand in order not to have the same issues in the future. This is the concept of *variable scope*.

**Variable scope is the areas of the program that have access to a variable.**

Modern programming languages have strict rules about what can be *in scope* and what is *out of scope*. For example, a variable declared inside a function or a subroutine has scope only within the function. It cannot be accessed outside the function.

```
Public Sub MySubHere(ByVal x as Long)
    Dim a as Long
    a = x
    x  = 100
End Sub 

' variable "a" does not exist outside the sub
```

In the example above the variable `a` is declared inside the subroutine (The `Dim` statement) and the variable `x` is an argument (by value)  passed into the subroutine. Like with the statement `Call MySubHere(10)`. Both variables are *in scope* inside the sub.

You can pass a variable outside a subroutine with two ways

1. Declare a function and assign the variable to the function name. This allows you to return *one* value from a procedure.

   ```
   Public Function MyFnHere(ByVal x as Long) as Long
      Dim a as Long
      a = 2*x+1
      MyFnHere = a
   End Function
   ```

   This is called by `aa = MyFnHere(bb)`, where `aa` and `bb` are variable declared in the scope where the function is called.
2. Declare one or more `ByRef` arguments and assign them inside the procedure. The `ByVal` keyword make a copy of the variables, and the `ByRef` keyword to keep a reference to the original value, allowing the subroutine to modify its value

   ```
   Public Sub MySubHere(ByVal x as Long, ByRef a as Long)
      a = 2*x+1
   End Sub
   ```

   This is called by `Call MySubHere(bb, aa)`, where `aa` and `bb` are variable declared in the scope where the function is called. This method allows for more than one variable to be "returned" by a procedure.

PS In VBA if you do not declare `ByVal` or `ByRef` for an argument it is assumed to be `ByRef`, which means functions can change the arguments. It is a good practice to **always include the `ByRef` and `ByVal` keywords when declaring arguments** to a function in order to avoid side-effects.

For example

```
Public Function MyEvilFn(x as Double) as Double
    x = 2*x
    MyEvilFn = x + 1
End Function
```

When called it has the following effect

```
Dim x as Double, y as Double
x = 1.0
y = MyEvilFn(x)
' At this point x=2.0 !!!
```

Comment: Many thanks John. I am going to save your answer here as well. Coding is not actually my area by nature (I am a Civil Engineer), but I am trying to get better in order to improve the small programs I am designing for my work.

Comment: Mechanical engineer here, so I understand. Also note a PS I added above.